# best schema model in my case (mongoose js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need advice on the schema.

For now, it looks as shown below:

```
const accountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  nickname:{
    index:true,
    type: String,
  },
  levels_scores: [Number],
  money: Number,
  skins: { circles: [Number], sticks: [Number], targets: [Number] },
  current_skins: { circles: Number, sticks: Number, targets: Number },
})
```

my queries are always filtered by nickname so I created index on it.

**I very often update money value :**

```
     saveMoney(req, res) {
    const nickname,money = req.body
  
  Accounts.findOneAndUpdate({ nickname:nickname},{money:money}),{useFindAndModify:false)
      res.sendStatus(200)
          }
```

Callback in the case will return all the document data which I don't need.**(levels_scores,skins etc.)** Performance waste I think

Am I thinking wrong?
Should I make schema with references,like money schema which stores only parent ID and money value?

I also have queries like:

```
 Accounts.findOne({ nickname: req.body.nickname }, (err, account) => {
      const part = req.body.skin[0]
      const skin_number = req.body.skin[1]

      account.skins[part].push(skin_number)
      account.markModified("skins")
      account.save()
      res.sendStatus(200)
    })
```

If i use .select("skins") method to not return all the document data, will I be able to save it?

*How would I do that to be the most performant?*

Comment: Could you explain clearly what do you want ?
I am unable to understand your question.

Comment: @DebasisDas Thanks for response. I edited my post.I would be grateful if you could spend some time with him again